# How to login gcp console without ssh?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, console, google-compute-engine

by mistake I have moved root files to subfolder in GCP Ubuntu server. Now i can't able to login via SSH.
I found some solution in stack overflow but in Google cloud it won't work. Without login how i can revert the files? so any other possibility to login to my server? Pls give a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try one of the following methods and see if they help:

1. Try to interacting with the [Serial Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) and try to run commands to revert the files to their original folder.
2. Implement the following steps:

   A. [Create a Snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots) from the existing disk of the instance.

   B. [Restore the snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-and-delete-snapshots#restoresnapshotlargersize) to a new disk and [attach the disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk) to another instance. After mounting the disk in that instance, perform reverting files on the disk. Create a [custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#bundle_image) from the new disk and create [a new instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#creating_an_instance_from_a_custom_image) from that custom image. Check if this new instance boots successfully. You can then delete the original malfunctioning instance.

Answer (score 0):

First login with web console
Create new user "adduser username".
Set password .
Edit sshd_config."nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config".
Find passwordauthentication no . Change no to yes .like passwordauthentication yes

And save the file close connection and try without ssh